# Group data in a bar chart excel

Tags: excel, vba, charts, bar-chart

I recently was tasked with creating a bar chart with these characteristics:
Data is collected quarterly
Each station has various collection points (different amount)
all points that belong to the same station should be the same color
each time frame should be different color.

Something like this:
[image: Bar Chart and data points]

In order to do that, i had to select the data, insert bar chart, switch row and column, delete empty legend(Since I have merged cells for q1 and q2), and manually change color for each of the bars for "a" and "b".

Please help and thank you!!!

Comment: If this is a programming related question please show the code you have tried. If it is a general computing question this is off-topic here and should be asked at https://superuser.com

Comment: I haven't actually tried a code for this, as I am very new at this. I was just wondering if it is possible to do this more efficiently. Not doing the same thing over and over again. I don't know if it counts as general computing question